# Finding a very smooth diffeomorphism between two very smooth diffeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

The assertion below looks like “folklore” and “well-known” to me, though I’m not totally sure. Any pointers welcome.

Let $\mathcal K$ denote the set of all ${\mathcal C}^{\infty}$-diffeomorphisms
$[0,1] \to [0,1]$. Let $f\in {\mathcal K}$. Let $a$ be a number between
$0$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})$. Then there exists a $g\in {\mathcal K}$ with
$0 \leq g \leq f$ and $g(\frac{1}{2})=a$.

Comment: Can't you just take a convex combination $g = (1-\alpha)f_1 + \alpha f_2$ for a suitable $\alpha$?

Comment: @Martin I changed my initial question, hopefully it is more interesting now

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $f$ is increasing. Than denote: 
$$A= \frac{a}{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Than take function $p\in C^\infty[0,1]$ which satisfy:

$$p(0) = \frac{A}{2}$$
$$p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = A$$
$$p(1) = 1$$
$$p'(x) > 0 \qquad x \in [0,1]$$

Surely such a function exists. I'll try to find example.

Than $g(x)=p(x)f(x)$ is that $g$ you are looking for.

See that 
$$g(0) = p(0)f(0) = \frac{A}{2} \cdot 0 = 0$$
$$g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{a}{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = a $$
$$g(1) = p(1)f(1) = 1$$
$$g'(x) = p'(x)f(x) + p(x)f'(x) > 0 \qquad x\in [0,1]$$

Comment: Damn it is wrong I'll fix it in a minute!